# Can I tell browser-sync to always use one .html file? (for html5mode links)

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

I use browser-sync (https://github.com/shakyShane/browser-sync) in my gulp file for development purposes. I want to use html5mode within my angular app. For that server needs to route multiple url patterns to single html file. Staging and production servers already do that but I would also like to have this up and running during development.

Here is how I run `browser-sync` server (part of `gulpfile.js`):

```
gulp.task('serve', function () {
    browserSync.init(null, {
        server: {
            baseDir: [APP_PATH]
        }
    });

    // watch only for app specific codes;
    ...
});
```

Just to make it more clear, at my app js I instruct angular to use html5mode for routing:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Within my APP_PATH I have single `index.html` which is served when I access `browser-sync` server. What I need is that `browser-sync` serves this single file for each paths.

So for example if I try to reach `/users/2` path starting from root path everything is fine; however if I refresh page or try to reach `/users/2` directly, `browser-sync` tells that it cannot find proper document to serve - this is all good and understandable but I wonder if there is any way to tell `browser-sync` built-in server to serve one file only. If not, can anyone suggest other options? Should I simply run express server and tell `browser-sync` to proxy through it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use https://github.com/tinganho/connect-modrewrite.

```
var modRewrite  = require('connect-modrewrite');

gulp.task('serve', function () {
    browserSync.init(null, {
        server: {
            baseDir: [APP_PATH],
            middleware: [
                modRewrite([
                    '!\\.\\w+$ /index.html [L]'
                ])
            ]
        }
    });

   // watch only for app specific codes;
   ...
});
```

Comment: Note that you should be passing your `server` config as the first parameter int `.init()` function. Take a look at [here](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/api#api-init) and [here](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options#option-server).

Answer (score 17):

From https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/issues/204#issuecomment-102623643

First install `connect-history-api-fallback`:

```
npm --save-dev install connect-history-api-fallback
```

Then add it to your gulpfile.js:

```
var historyApiFallback = require('connect-history-api-fallback');

gulp.task('serve', function() {
  browserSync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: "app",
      middleware: [ historyApiFallback() ]
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: can u tell me how to change the base file path name when using connect-history-api-fallback like its done using connect-modrewrite?

Comment: @GopinathShiva what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want the browserSync to work with respect to different angular route urls. The thing is when I went to some route urls say, https://example.com/someroute. And when browserSync reload the pages, its showing the error that its unable to fetch files from that route. Am I clear? Anyways for me the solution given using connect-modrewrite works, Am just asking you whether is there any workaround using connect-history-api-fallback too?

Comment: That's the whole point of using `connect-history-api-fallback`, it should always load `index.html`, no matter the route. Have a look at their documentation, maybe it will help: https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback

Comment: Did you get this working with your browserSync config? I am having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

In version 2.23.0 you can use `single` option, like this:

```js
gulp.task('serve', function () {
    browserSync.init(null, {
        server: {
            baseDir: [APP_PATH]
        },
        single: true
    });

    // watch only for app specific codes;
    ...
});
```

Reference: https://browsersync.io/docs/options#option-single

Comment: I tried to do this but it doesn't seem to be doing anything, refreshes to the page just do the same thing as if no route was configured, but links from within the app work as expected. Using v2.26.3, and running it with "browser-sync start --config bs-config.js". Is there any more info that might help, because the docs about it are slim pickings?